# sonarqube: Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true"

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonarqube complains that the condition

`if(inputMsgPath==null || outputFormat==null || swiftStdsVersion==null)`

(see snippet below) always evaluates to true, but it doesn't. Is this just a sonarqube bug?

```
String inputMsgPath = null;
String outputFormat = null;
String swiftStdsVersion = null;
String assertionsPath = null;
List<Assertion> assertions = null;

for( int i=0; i<args.length; i+=2){
    if("-i".equals(args[i])){
        inputMsgPath = args[++i];
    }
    else if("-o".equals(args[i])){
        outputFormat = args[++i];
    }
    else if("-s".equals(args[i])){
        swiftStdsVersion = args[++i];
    }
    else if("-a".equals(args[i])){
        assertionsPath = args[++i];
    }
}

if(inputMsgPath==null || outputFormat==null || swiftStdsVersion==null){
    printSyntax();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the snippet to show the declaration of those vars and their uses before the `for` loop

Comment: OK, edited as requested

Comment: I believe the code is surely wrong, apart from Sonarqube FP, since you might just grab behind the end of your array.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by this: "you might just grab behind the end of your array".  How? This is a main method. The args array is taken from the command line (by the JRE). Higher up (not shown in the snippet) I check that the number of arguments is even.

Comment: You didn’t show that. Also, it’s not enough, the arguments can be `foo -i`, which is an even number of arguments, and `foo` is just ignored. Anyway, it’s not important for your question.

Comment: Right. Would be nice to discuss the actual question :|

Comment: To make you happy I now increment i in 2s :)